# Send email and get reply in laravel form

Tags: laravel, email

I'm succeed to send mail from contact form, and now my requirement  is to get automated success reply to the users input email address when submitting the form. please help me on this

ContactUsController

```php
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
  use App\Mail\ContactUs;

  class ContactUsController extends Controller
  {
    function index()
    {
      return view('home/contactus');
    }

    function send(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
      ]);

      $data = array(
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'subject' => $request->subject,
                'message' => $request->message
            );

      \Mail::to('xxx@mail.com')->send(new ContactUs($data));
      return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you soon.');
    }   
  }
```

ContactUs

```php
<?php

  namespace App\Mail;

  use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
  use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
  use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

  class ContactUs extends Mailable
  {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
      $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
      return $this->from('xxxx@mail.com')
                  ->subject('Customer Feedback')
                  ->view('dynamic_email_template')
                  ->with('data', $this->data);
    }
  }
```

Form

```html
<div class="form">

  <h4>Send us a message</h4>
  @if (count($errors) > 0)
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
  @endif 
  @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
    <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
  </div>
  @endif

  <form method="post" action="{{url('contactus/send')}}" autocomplete="off">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" for="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" for="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" for="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" for="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <div class="validation"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" name="send" title="Send Message">Send Message</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

dynamic_email_template

```html
<p>Hi, This is {{ $data['name'] }} "{{ $data['email'] }}"</p> </br>

<p>{{ $data['subject'] }}</p> </br>
<p>I have some query like "{{ $data['message'] }}".</p> </br>
<p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback.</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create email template same like your view file, lets say `contact_us_email.blade.php`. In this file add this content

`contact_us_email.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hi, This is {{ $data['name'] }} "{{ $data['email'] }}"</h2><br>
        <p>Subject: {{ $data['subject'] }}</p> <br>
        <p>I have some query like <b>"{{ $data['message'] }}"</b>. <br>
        <p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: Add css or styling according to your need. this is basic html

`Edit: To send confirmation email to user`

For success confirmation to user, you can create another email template like 
`contact_us_thank_you_email.blade.php`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello, {{ $data['name'] }} "{{ $data['email'] }}"</h2><br>
        <p>Thank You for your interest...blah blah blah</p> <br>
        <p>Our team will contact you soon</p> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now in your `ContactUsController`, replace

```
\Mail::to('xxx@mail.com')->send(new ContactUs($data));
```

with

```
Mail::send('contact_us_email', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('xxx@mail.com', 'xxx');
    $message->to('xxx@mail.com')->subject($data['subject']);
});

Mail::send('contact_us_thank_you_email', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('xxx@mail.com', 'xxx');
    $message->to($data['email'])->subject('Thank you for the interest');
});
```

And I think you are good to go with this. I hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: I'm expecting, when user sends message from contact form. that he will get success message to his mail.

Comment: @JyothibabuNanipini please find edit in answer for the same

Comment: That might be due to we are trying to access a variable which is not found, could you tell me where you are getting this, so that I can help you

Comment: in the contact_us_email of  {{ $data['name'] }}

Comment: hello can any one help me please

Comment: please try $name instead of $data['name]

Comment: getting error  -----htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,